# Controlling Light Color in Array

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, lighting

I have a single vertex using a modifier array with area lights parented to it. I'm animating the light colors to change over time based on their position within the world.

This is working but the gradient shape gets squeezed as I approach the max value. I want it to evenly pass over the lights based on their positions, can't figure out my math!

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you want it to spread even, first of all: why do you set the _Color Ramp_ interpolation to _Ease_? If you want it even, set it to _Linear_. The next thing is: you multiply the Z value. The _Color Ramp_ converts input values from 0 to 1. The _Generated_ output creates Z values from 0 to 1. If you multiply these by let's say 0.1, the Z values range from 0 to 0.1, which means they never reach the end of the _Color Ramp_ because that's 1.

Comment: Thank you! How do I mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: You cannot accept this as answer, because it is just a comment.